# What do you recommend using for graphically visualizing a WSDL?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm looking for a good solution for graphically viewing a SOAP-based web service and possibly interacting with it (for testing purposes). Online (browser-based) solutions would be interesting too.

Comment: This looks like something you wanted: [http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTest.html](http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTest.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've had success with a combination of the Elipse WTP WSDL Editor and SoapUI.

Eclipse WTP WSDL Editor -http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor

SoapUI - http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: To add this into Eclipse, add the following repository: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo/ then browse packages

Answer (score 23):

Try this (online) WSDL viewer:

http://tomi.vanek.sk/

Comment: Very handy tool for converting WSDL into nice HTML documentation - and unlike some tools I've tried (including Oxygen) it actually displays the request and response message structures against the operations, rather than just referring to the message part name... Thanks for the link!

Comment: Is this link dead (for good)?

Comment: Archive.org has your back: [Version from 2017-11-13](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113171145/http://tomi.vanek.sk:80/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer) _that's why you shouldn't block everything in robots.txt_

Comment: Source code at https://github.com/tomi-vanek/wsdl-viewer

Answer (score 4):

I have used SOAP UI with success in the past:

http://www.soapui.org/information/WSDL_Test.html?gclid=CMOpgKnAjpgCFRBbagodxyzOqg

It allows you test methods and to see if your WSDL passes current standards.

Answer (score 1):

XMLSpy....nothing beats it (^-^)

Comment: I'd say that soapUI beats it as far as testing goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view it, try https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2html. It's simple.

---

Edit:  the url has been changed to https://github.com/chenjianjx/wsdl2html

Comment: this url no more exists